# Two arrays, replacing the ID in one with the description of the other (matching ids) Powershell

Tags: powershell

Im new to PowerShell, currently in the process of Learning, hope you guys can help me out.

I currently have what I understand are 2 arrays I can call their properties and positions with $ticket.id[0] , $categories.name[0] etc:

**Ticket List**

name: TicketName

Category ID: 1

Name: TicketName2

Category ID: 3

---

**Categories**

Category ID: 1

Name: Networking

Category ID: 3

Category Name: Printer

I would like to replace the value in Category ID (Ticket List) for the actual name on every ticket, currently I have tried for eachs and compare but have only gotten it to write all names into the id field.

Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Can you show us your code first please. SO isn't a code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to attack a problem like this.  However I would suggest first understanding what you are doing.  You need a relationship between the data in was set versus the other.  You need to go through each record in the `$Tickets` array, find the correct data from the `$Categories` array and reassign it to the correct property of the current object in the `$Tickets` array.

A great way to do this is to use a hash table.  You can think of this as a table of key value pairs, I like to think of it as an index.  A hash would facilitate multiple approaches as it merely provides a way to look up one value by another.  This would also bear some similarity to a record's key field in a DB system like SQL.

Example:

```
# Simulates your description of the ticket array.
$tickets =
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'Mr. Jones Ticket'
        'Category ID' = 1
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = 'Mrs. Smith Ticket'
        'Category ID' = 2
    }
)

# Simulates your description of the categories array.
$Categories =
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Category ID' = 1
        Name = 'Networking'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Category ID' = 2
        Name = 'Printer'
    }
)

# Create a Hash Table so you can relate the 2 sets of objects.
# Use the presumably unique Category ID as the key and the name 
# as the value.
$CategoryIndex = @{}
$Categories | 
ForEach-Object{
    $CategoryIndex.Add( $_.'Category ID', $_.Name)
}

# For each object in the $Tickets array lookup the category name from the new 
# CategoryIndex hash table and set the Category ID property of the current object
$Tickets |
ForEach-Object{
    $_.'Category ID' = $CategoryIndex[$_.'Category ID']
}

# Output the $Ticket array to demonstrate the the Category ID property 
# no holds the name not the number.
$Tickets
```

There are probably lots of ways to do this, but this is straight forward. Moreover, hash used lots of things in PowerShell & you are just starting out I think this is the best way for now.

Comment: Thank you so much, Steven. with some tweaking I was able to adjust this into my script using inputs i already had as hash tables.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out.  If you're comfortable, and I only mention because you're a new contributor, but please accept the answer.